# Bot message deleting on react

Tags: python, discord.py

Basically, the reaction works like a "refresh" button to redo the command (aka make a new message) when reacted to

Everything else works apart from the message deleting when reacted to: it just stays there
(Part of command)

```py
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 await msg.add_reaction("")
 try:
   await bot.wait_for(
     "reaction_add",
      timeout=1000.0, 
      check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji == "" and reaction.message == msg,
        )
 except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    try:
      await msg.remove_reaction("", bot.user)
    except discord.NotFound:
            pass
 else:
    await rlgarage(ctx, arg=arg)
    await msg.delete()
```

Comment: Put the deletion before `rlgarage()`

Comment: lmao it was that simple tysm

Answer (score 0):

put `await msg.delete()` before `await rlgarage(ctx, arg=arg)`